# Show website that only accepts POST method in a WebView

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview

I am working on a mobile application developed with Xamarin and I have encountered a problem when trying to display a Website in a WebView.

```
  <WebView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="webView" source="https://ecommerce.netpay.com.mx/a-webapp3/e-commerce/web-authorizer?checkoutTokenId=fc912ec2-5f20-4533-91cf-95db61d26822" WidthRequest="700" HeightRequest="700" />
```

When running the application it shows me the following error. I understand that this happens when the method I am using is not correct.

[image: Response WebView]

Then I tried the following in the code behind:

```
 private async Task urlAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var url = "https://ecommerce.netpay.com.mx/a-webapp3/e-commerce/web-authorizer?checkoutTokenId=fc912ec2-5f20-4533-91cf-95db61d26822";
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
            var readAsStringAsync = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var stringHtml = readAsStringAsync.Result;
            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = stringHtml
            };
            webView.Source = html;

        }
```

And I removed the "source" property from the WebView tag. But this did not work properly because the site does not fully load. 
[image: WebViewResponse]

Finally I create a Web project and this works:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="https://ecommerce.netpay.com.mx/a-webapp3/e-commerce/web-authorizer?checkoutTokenId=0a377ca8-e26c-4f22-a751-52719acf9019&checkoutDetail=true&MerchantResponseURL=aHR0cHM6Ly9nb29nbGUuY29t" method="POST" target="_blank">
  JWT: <input type="text" name="jwt"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Haga clic en el botón Enviar y la entrada se enviará a una página del servidor llamada "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to implement it in Xamarin? Thank you.

Comment: You are firing a get request where it has post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to acces the `PostUrl` method of the underliying Android WebView. As it's not exposed by the default WebView you need to create a derived webview and a custom renderer:

```
//Derived class in your forms project
public class PostWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty PostUrlProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PostUrl), typeof(string), typeof(PostWebView), string.Empty, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string PostUrl
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PostUrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PostUrlProperty, value); }
    }

    public byte[] PostData { get; set; } = new byte[0];
}

//Custom renderer on the native project
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PostWebView), typeof(PostWebViewRenderer))]
namespace (your project namespace).Droid
{
    public class PostWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public PostWebViewRenderer(Context ctx) : base(ctx) {  }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "PostUrl")
            {
                if (Control == null)
                    return;

                var web = (Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;
                var view = Element as PostWebView;
                web.PostUrl(view.PostUrl, view.PostData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can POST navigate using the new property `PostUrl`, also, you can add any data you need to POST to the server using `PostData`.

```
//You can set it to new byte[0] if you don't need to send any data.
postView.PostData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("param1=1&param2=2");
//Now set tyhe URL to navigate
postView.PostUrl = "http://myserver.com/my/post/url";
```

If you need to bind this with XAML or set `PostUrl` before the control has been created you will need to hook the `ElementChanged` event, check if the `PostUrl` property and if it has been set call the `PostUrl` method of the Android WebView.